# Drop view if exists in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I'm new to the Oracle database system. What is the equivalent of the below SQL statement in Oracle 12c?

```
DROP VIEW IF EXIST <view_name>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Except from simply calling `DROP VIEW`, you can write [a procedure](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Oracle/0160__View/Ifviewexistsdropview.htm) that checks before:

> ```
> BEGIN
>  FOR i IN (SELECT null FROM user_views WHERE view_name = 'BOOKS_emp') LOOP
>    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP VIEW books_emp';
>  END LOOP;
> END;
> /
> ```

Answer (score 0):

What you've written is working in 12c without any issue. Also, you can simply use,

```
DROP VIEW <VIEW_NAME>;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something via a procedure, but your query is irrelevant when you can run drop view viewname. It can straightaway show you if it exists or not.

```
  Create or Replace Procedure
      dropifexists(viewname IN
         varchar(50))
      AS
          Declare
          flag number(10);

      Begin
          SELECT count(*) into flag FROM
              user_views
              WHERE view_name = viewname;

          If(flag>0)
              Drop View viewname;
          Else
             dbms_output.putline('View already
             exists')
          End if;
      End;
      /
```

And, once created, you can call the same procedure:

```
   begin
       dropifexists('viewname' ) ;
   end;
   /
```

Comment: You also might want to explain how to use it..

Comment: Yes @Raymond ive added the code to call the procedure. Thanks!

Comment: `DROP VIEW` would need to be dynamic SQL.

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure you want to replace this functionality 1:1?  Normally, you'd do a `DROP VIEW IF EXISTS` in SQL Server because until recently, SQL Server didn't have a `CREATE OR ALTER VIEW` option.  So your promotion scripts would drop the view if it existed and then have a `CREATE VIEW` statement so it could be run multiple times without a problem.

Oracle has always (well, at least the past couple of decades) supported a `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW` statement, so your Oracle scripts would normally just contain a CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW statement.  There wouldn't normally be any need to try to drop the view first.

You'd only want to drop the view if it was an obsolete object that you wanted to be removed permanently, but in that case you'd know that the view exists, so it wouldn't make a lot of sense to check for existence first.

Comment: it makes sense e.g. on db structure/view updates/releases where things may get obsolete