# How can I drop a view in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, view

I have a view defined in my Oracle database and I would like to drop it. How can I drop a view?

Comment: Hint:  `DROP VIEW`.

Comment: This may answer your question: [Drop view if exists in oracle sql](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57852474)

Comment: Kindly note that there is no such thing as a Question being too simple on Stack Overflow. Simple Questions are not off-topic.

Answer (score 3):

According to Oracle's documentation on [DROP VIEW (Oracle Database 20c)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/20/sqlrf/DROP-VIEW.html#GUID-1A1BD841-66B9-47E4-896F-D36E075AE296) the syntax (in the "Description of the illustration drop_view.eps") is:

> DROP VIEW [ schema. ] view [ CASCADE CONSTRAINTS ] ;

..which in the simplest form, if your viewname is `emp_view`, will be:

> `DROP VIEW emp_view;`

---

Note: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57852474/12695027) by [Chamithra Thenuwara](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2287769) to "Drop view if exists in oracle sql" also shows this.